# Como fazer um dump de um banco de dados MySQL com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Atualmente, para exportar somente a estrutura de determinado banco de dados, eu uso o seguinte:

```
mysqldump -h host -u usuario --no-data --database banco > dump.sql -psenha
```

Isso gera um arquivo SQL, tudo resolvido. No entanto, esse é um processo manual que me custa tempo, e posso esquecer de fazê-lo, então, pensei em fazer um script em PHP para automatizá-lo dentro do meu sistema. O problema é que não sei como fazer isso.

Eu gostaria de saber se existe algum comando SQL específico para que eu possa gerar esse arquivo. O requisito de ser em PHP é que posso precisar executar isso em um servidor compartilhado, aí teria várias restrições de outras linguagens (como shell script, utilizar o próprio `mysqldump`, etc.).

Comment: Calebe, segue algumas pergintas : O servidor roda em linux ou windows? Você possui acesso ao crontab para agendar alguma execução de Script? Caso seja linux e caso tenha acesso ao crontab, podes agendar a execução de um .sh.
O Shell seria responsável por chamar o mysqldump.

Comment: So pra lembrar, passei um trabalhão pra fazer funcionar o mysqldump, por que os sites não explicam que o cmd deve ser executado na pasta bin de onde esta instalado o mysql (não adianta copiar os arquivos "mysql.exe" e "mysqldump.exe" para o c:/system32 que ele não acha o banco de dados), oooou... fazer um comando anterior que leve o cmd para a pasta bin, dessa forma "cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin" (no meu caso esta instalado dentro do xampp). Espero ter ajudado nas instruções, valeu estava procurando como executar em php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei chegando à uma solução em PHP mesmo, baseado no script do site postado pelo @Gabriel Santos. Segue:

```
class DatabaseDump {
    private $db;
    private $host, $user, $pass, $dbname;
    private $sql, $removeAI;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $dbname) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->removeAI = true;

        try {
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.$dbname.';host='.$host, $user, $pass);
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();          
            die;
        }
    }

    private function ln($text = '') {
        $this->sql = $this->sql . $text . "\n";
    }

    public function dump($file) {
        $this->ln("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;\n");

        $tables = $this->db->query('SHOW TABLES')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $table = $table[0];
            $this->ln('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `'.$table.'`;');

            $schemas = $this->db->query("SHOW CREATE TABLE `{$table}`")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            foreach ($schemas as $schema) {
                $schema = $schema['Create Table'];
                if($this->removeAI) $schema = preg_replace('/AUTO_INCREMENT=([0-9]+)(\s{0,1})/', '', $schema);
                $this->ln($schema.";\n\n");
            }
        }

        file_put_contents($file, $this->sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: essa classe só exporta a estrutura da sql.

Answer (score 7):

Use a função `system` do PHP:

```
system('mysqldump -h host -u usuario --no-data --database banco > dump.sql -psenha');
```

Veja mais informações: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.system.php

E então é só criar um cronjob para que o script seja executado 1 vez por dia, ou conforme desejar.

---

Aqui uma maneira de receber uma cópia do banco de dados por e-mail:

```php
<?php
// Backup do site

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'usuario_aqui';
$dbpass = 'password_aqui';
$dbname = 'database_aqui';

// Seu e-mail aqui
$sendto = 'Eu <eu@exemplo.com>';

// O remetente. Pode ser backup@seusite.com
$sendfrom = 'Backup <backup@exemplo.com>';

// Assunto do e-mail
$sendsubject = 'Backup do site ' . date('d/m/Y');

// Corpo do e-mail
$bodyofemail = 'Backup diário do meu site';

$backupfile = 'Autobackup_' . date("Ymd") . '.sql';
$backupzip = $backupfile . '.tar.gz';
system("mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p$dbpass --lock-tables $dbname > $backupfile");
system("tar -czvf $backupzip $backupfile");

include('Mail.php');
include('Mail/mime.php');

$message = new Mail_mime();
$text = "$bodyofemail";
$message->setTXTBody($text);
$message->AddAttachment($backupzip);
$body = $message->get(array(
    'head_charset' => 'utf-8',
    'text_charset' => 'utf-8',
    'html_charset' => 'utf-8'
));
$extraheaders = array("From"=>"$sendfrom", "Subject"=>"$sendsubject");
$headers = $message->headers($extraheaders);
$mail = Mail::factory("mail");
$mail->send("$sendto", $headers, $body);

// Remover o arquivo do servidor (opcional)
unlink($backupzip);
unlink($backupfile);
?>
```

Não lembro quem criou o script acima originalmente. Só lembro de ter modificado o código um pouco.

Comment: Mas como ter certeza que o servidor me permitirá utilizar o `mysqldump`?

Comment: Se a função ``system`` estiver habilitada, o mysqldump vai funcionar. O único problema é que algumas hospedagens compartilhadas bloqueiam o uso dessa função, por ser perigosa.

Comment: Infelizmente, como tinha dito na pergunta, não posso executar em meu servidor. `Warning: system() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/... on line 48`

Comment: Então veja http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php. O link é antigo, mas fazendo algumas adaptações pode funcionar. Vou testar mais tarde.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Use o `crontab` para agendar tarefas de backup, além de compactar os bancos com `gzip`, o que deixa o tamanho dos backups muito menor.

Para agendar tarefas com o `crontab`, supondo que você tenha as devidas permissões no sistema, execute o comando `crontab -e`.

Por exemplo, no meu caso eu uso o `crontab` para agendar uym backup diário do meu banco:

```
0 * * * * /bin/sh /home/ec2-user/sh/backup_mysql.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

E dentro do `backup_mysql.sh` eu deixo diversos comandos `mysqldump`, no modelo abaixo:

```
mysqldump -u<usuario> -p<senha> <banco> | gzip > /home/ec2-user/backups/mysql/<banco>-`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`.sql.gz
```

Essa é o que eu acredito ser a melhor prática para uma rotina de backups periódicos de bancos de dados. Tente usar esse modelo para encontrar o que melhgor serve a seus propósitos.

Answer (score 1):

#### mysqldump

A coisa não é tão simples assim. É melhor usar o `mysqldump` a partir do PHP com `shell_exec` ou `system`, ou simplesmente agendar um *cronjob*, conforme sugerido.

Eu particularmente uso *cronjob* a partir de um sistema remoto, que chama o `mysqldump`, gerando meus *backup diários* do banco de dados de pequenas aplicações de clientes meus por aí.

---

#### $this->dbutil->backup()

Certa ocasião, o servidor do provedor chato que hospedava a aplicação do projeto no qual eu estava trabalhando não permitia acesso remoto ao MySQL de jeito nenhum. Eu não tinha acesso SSH. O `mysqldump` não era uma opção. Não tinha um *phpMyAdmin* da vida pra me gerar um *dump*.

De modo que os desenvolvedores anteriores até já tinham feito o seu script PHP que fazia as *queries*, desde `SHOW TABLES` até tudo o mais que você imaginar, e montava o respectivo arquivo SQL, contendo o *dump*.

O problema é que não funcionava. Mas ninguém sabia disso. Aparentemente tudo ia bem. Porém, certas *strings* eram truncadas. Só "descobri" isso porque usando a minha versão local da aplicação, de repente notei um conteúdo ligeiramente diferente da aplicação remota. Fiquei intrigado, e investigando cheguei ao fato de que o script não funcionava suficientemente bem para gerar um *dump* fiel.

A solução que encontrei foi o [método `backup` da **Database Utility Class** do Code Igniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/utilities.html#backup). Consegui enfim obter meu *dump* 100% à prova de balas, a partir do PHP.

A implementação dessa função que gera o *dump* é uma tarefa delicada. Recomendo que dê uma olhada no [código da função `backup` no repositório do Code Igniter](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/e90d8571d042c4913266b585a067f54007f2ee96/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_utility.php#L67) ([tem que dar uma olhada aqui também](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/e90d8571d042c4913266b585a067f54007f2ee96/system/database/DB_utility.php#L310)). O pessoal do projeto que trabalhei tentou reinventar essa roda e falhou.

Portanto, se **precisar** obter um *dump* de um banco de dados MySQL com PHP, sugiro que utilize essa função, ou que faça a sua versão a partir dessa, que comprovadamente funciona.

Exemplo de código:

```
// Carrega a classe de utilidades de banco de dados
$this->load->dbutil();

// Coloca o dump de todo o seu banco de dados numa variável
$backup =& $this->dbutil->backup(); 

// Gravando o dump num arquivo
$this->load->helper('file');
write_file('/path/to/mybackup.gz', $backup); 

// Enviando o arquivo para o navegador
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download('mybackup.gz', $backup);
```

Configurações para o *dump* podem ser feitas através de um *array* de opções, a ser utilizado como o primeiro parâmetro para a função de backup. Por exemplo:

```
$prefs = array(
    'tables'      => array('table1', 'table2'),  // Tabelas para incluir no dump
    'ignore'      => array(),           // Tabelas para não incluir no dump
    'format'      => 'txt',             // gzip, zip, txt
    'filename'    => 'mybackup.sql',    // Nome do arquivo - APENAS PARA FORMATO ZIP
    'add_drop'    => TRUE,              // Incluir comandos DROP TABLE no dump
    'add_insert'  => TRUE,              // Incluir os dados das tabelas em comandos INSERT no dump
    'newline'     => "\n"               // Caracter para final de linha a ser usado no dump
);

$this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é isso que você precisa, mas segue um código completo pra fazer bkp do seu banco de dados, só salvar o código em um arquivo php, criar uma pasta chamada "db_bkp" e não esquecer de preencher os dados de acesso ao banco de dados

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_erros',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);//force php to show any error message

backup_tables(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);//don't forget to fill with your own database access informations

function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name)
{
    $link = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysqli_select_db($link, $name);
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW TABLES');
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
        {
            $tables[$i] = $row[0];
            $i++;
        }
    $return = "";
    foreach($tables as $table)
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
        $return .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.';';
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($link, 'SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j < $num_fields; $j++)
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                }
                $return.= ");\n";
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }
    //save file
    $handle = fopen('db_bkp/db-backup-'.time().'-'.(md5(implode(',',$tables))).'.sql','w+');//Don' forget to create a folder to be saved, "db_bkp" in this case
    fwrite($handle, $return);
    fclose($handle);
    echo "bkp efetuado com sucesso";//Sucessfuly message
}
?>
```

Comment: Olá, seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em português, por favor evite ficar repetindo suas respostas em diversas perguntas! Quando você tiver pontos suficiente poderá inserir comentários em todas as peguntas e assim,  caso ache que sua resposta possa ajudar mais de um pergunta insira nos comentários da outra pergunta o link da sua resposta.

Answer (score 1):

```
// aqui esta o script para tal função funcionando perfeitamente e testado
// exaustivamente em meu servidor; não inventei nada somente fiz a junção de
// uma parte de código que peguei aqui e uma outra parte de um outro lugar e // efetuei pequenas correções; Não necessita de mais nada além do código
// na tarefa CRON inclua php -q /home/usuariodosite/pasta aonde esta o script

<?php
// Backup do banco de dados do site

$dbhost = 'localhost';          //local aonde se encontra o banco de dados
$dbuser = '---';    // usuário do banco de dados
$dbpass = '---';         // senha do usuário do banco de dados
$dbname = '---';   // nome do banco de dados

// rotina que faz o backup não mexer

$backupfile = 'Autobackup_' . date("Ymd") . '.sql';
$backupzip = $backupfile . '.tar.gz';
system("mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p$dbpass --lock-tables $dbname > $backupfile");
system("tar -czvf $backupzip $backupfile");

// ROTINA DE ENVIO DO EMAIL COM O ANEXO 

$to = "---";         //Quem vai receber o email
$from = "---";  //Quem está enviando (Endereço a ser apresentado como da pessoa que está enviando)
$subject = 'Backup do Banco de Dados Sql ';          //Assunto do email
$messagem = 'cópia do backup do banco de dados Sql'; //Mensagem a ser enviada
$path = "---";                  //Diretório onde o arquivo a ser enviado está salvo
$filename = "$backupzip";                        //Nome do arquivo anexo a ser enviado - não mexer aqui

// ---------- Não altere nada deste ponto em diante ----------

$headers = 'From: ' .     "$from\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . "$from\r\n";

$file = $path . "/" . $filename;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$separator = md5(time());   // a random hash será necessário para separar conteúdos diversos a serem enviados
$eol = PHP_EOL;   // Define o retorno de carro a ser utilizado

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers = "From: < $from >" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol . $eol;

// messagem
$headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= $messagem . $eol . $eol;

// attachment
$headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= $content . $eol . $eol;
$headers .= "--" . $separator . "--";

//SEND Mail

if (mail($to, $subject, "", $headers)) {
   echo "Sucesso no envio do Email";
} else {
   echo "Erro! Não foi possível enviar o email solicitado";
}

// Remover o arquivo do servidor (opcional)
unlink($backupzip);
unlink($backupfile);
?>
```

Comment: Oi Amauri! Podes explicar qual é a(s) linha(s) do teu código que respondem à pergunta _"Como fazer um dump de um banco de dados MySQL"_?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um tutorial completo e atualizado para resolver sua necessidade:

https://startinn.com.br/blog/post?p=93_realizando-backup-automatico-do-banco-em-servidor-de-hospedagem-linux-com-php

Com ele é possível criar uma cópia do banco MySQL de maneira automática utilizando um arquivo PHP e uma tarefa CRON. O arquivo é compactado com ZIP.