# Criação de banco de dados MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou iniciando com banco de dados MySQL, e gostaria de tirar umas dúvidas. Andei dando uma pesquisada mas mesmo assim não consegui sanar essas dúvidas. Seriam elas:

1. Observei que na criação da tabela tem uma ENGINE - InnoDB, para que serve isso?
2. Tem algum padrão a se seguir na criação do banco de dados e das suas tabelas no MySQL? Padrão esses como, setar o charset, colocar esse ENGINE nas tabelas, etc, para que futuramente não sofra/ocorra algum problema caso necessite realizar algo que não foi mudado no início da criação do banco de dados.
3. Em relação ao Backup e restauração. É um procedimento feito via programação de acordo com a linguagem que está se utilizando ou é feito na máquina do qual está localizado o servidor do MySQL?
4. Se possível tiver mais algumas dicas, opiniões para manter o banco de dados consistentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## O que são Engines de Armazenamento?

Engines de armazenamento, ou mecanismos de armazenamento, são componentes MySql que controlam as operações SQL para diferentes tipos de tabela que armazenam e gerenciam informações em um Banco de Dados.
InnoDB é o mecanismo de armazenamento comumente utilizado como mecanismo de propósito geral e a partir da versão MySQL 5.5, e posteriores, é o engine na falta(default) ou seja na falta de uma escolha o InnoDB é o engine padrão do sistema.

Existem alguns mecanismos de armazenamento em MySql e eles são utilizados para diferentes propósitos:

**InnoDB**

Este é o mecanismo de armazenamento padrão para o MySQL 5.5 e superior. Ele fornece tabelas seguras a transações (compatíveis com ACID), suporta restrições de integridade referencial FOREIGN KEY. Ele suporta os recursos de confirmação, reversão e recuperação de falhas para proteger os dados. Ele também suporta bloqueio em nível de linha. É "leituras nonlocking consistentes" aumenta o desempenho quando usado em um ambiente multiusuário. Ele armazena dados em índices clusterizados que reduzem a E / S de consultas com base em chaves primárias.

**MyISAM**

São tabelas de pouco impacto na memória. O bloqueio no nível de tabela limita o desempenho em cargas de trabalho de leitura / gravação, por isso é frequentemente usado em cargas de trabalho somente leitura ou principalmente leitura em configurações de Web e armazenamento de dados.
Cada tabela MyISAM é armazenada no disco em dois arquivos. Os arquivos têm nomes que começam com o nome da tabela e têm uma extensão para indicar o tipo de arquivo. O arquivo de dados tem uma extensão .MYD (MYData). O arquivo de índice possui uma extensão .MYI (MYIndex). A definição da tabela é armazenada no dicionário de dados do MySQL.

**Memory**

Armazena todos os dados na RAM, para acesso rápido em ambientes que exigem pesquisas rápidas de dados não críticos. Esse mecanismo era conhecido anteriormente como o mecanismo HEAP. Seus casos de uso estão diminuindo; O InnoDB com sua área de memória do buffer pool fornece uma maneira geral e durável de manter a maioria ou todos os dados na memória, e o NDBCLUSTER fornece pesquisas rápidas de valores-chave para enormes conjuntos de dados distribuídos.

**CSV**

Suas tabelas são realmente arquivos de texto com valores separados por vírgulas. As tabelas CSV permitem importar ou descarregar dados no formato CSV para trocar dados com scripts e aplicativos que lêem e escrevem no mesmo formato. Como as tabelas CSV não são indexadas, você normalmente mantém os dados em tabelas InnoDB durante a operação normal e só usa tabelas CSV durante o estágio de importação ou exportação.

**Archive**

Essas tabelas compactas e não indexadas destinam-se a armazenar e recuperar grandes quantidades de informações históricas, arquivadas ou de auditoria de segurança raramente referenciadas.
O mecanismo ARCHIVE suporta INSERT, REPLACE e SELECT, mas não DELETE ou UPDATE. Ele suporta operações ORDER BY, colunas BLOB e tipos de dados espaciais. Sistemas de referência espacial geográfica não são suportados. O mecanismo ARCHIVE usa o bloqueio em nível de linha.

**Blackhole**

O mecanismo de armazenamento Blackhole aceita, mas não armazena dados, semelhante ao dispositivo Unix `/dev/null`. Consultas sempre retornam um conjunto vazio. Essas tabelas podem ser usadas em configurações de replicação nas quais as instruções DML são enviadas para servidores escravos, mas o servidor mestre não mantém sua própria cópia dos dados.

**NDB**

Também conhecido como `NDBCLUSTER`, esse é um mecanismo de banco de dados em cluster e é particularmente adequado para aplicativos que exigem o mais alto grau possível de tempo de atividade e disponibilidade.
É uma versão de alta disponibilidade e alta redundância do mecanismo MySQL adaptado para o ambiente de computação distribuída. As séries recentes de versões do NDB Cluster usam a versão 8 do mecanismo de armazenamento NDB para permitir a execução de vários computadores com servidores MySQL e outros softwares em um cluster.

**Merge**

Permite que um DBA ou desenvolvedor MySQL agrupe logicamente uma série de tabelas MyISAM idênticas e as refira como um único objeto. Bom para ambientes VLDB, como data warehousing.

**Federated**

Oferece a capacidade de vincular servidores MySQL separados para criar um banco de dados lógico a partir de vários servidores físicos. Muito bom para ambientes distribuídos ou de repositórios.

Há ainda o tipo `Example` que é apenas um exemplo para desenvolvedores criarem os seus próprios mecanismos.

---

## O que é Charset?

Charset é a codificação de caracteres.

ASCII foi o primeiro padrão de codificação de caracteres (também chamado de conjunto de caracteres). O ASCII definiu 128 caracteres alfanuméricos diferentes que podem ser usados na Internet: números (0-9), letras inglesas (A-Z) e alguns caracteres especiais como! $ + - () @ <>.

ISO-8859-1 era o conjunto de caracteres padrão para HTML 4. Esse conjunto de caracteres também suportava 256 códigos de caracteres diferentes.

ANSI (Windows-1252) foi o conjunto de caracteres original do Windows. ANSI é idêntico ao ISO-8859-1, exceto que o ANSI tem 32 caracteres extras.

Como o ANSI e o ISO-8859-1 eram tão limitados, o HTML 4 também suportava o UTF-8.

UTF-8 (Unicode) abrange quase todos os caracteres e símbolos do mundo.

Hoje codificação de caracteres padrão para HTML5 é UTF-8.

---

## Backup

Quanto a terceira pergunta, o backup tanto pode ser feito na máquina ou via script
De uma lida nessa pergunta [Como fazer um dump de um banco de dados MySQL com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4263/como-fazer-um-dump-de-um-banco-de-dados-mysql-com-php).

---

## Uma dica?

Mantenha a leitura sempre atualizada.

Comment: Show de bola, gostei bastante!
Sanou todas as minhas dúvidas.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, o ideal é separar as perguntas, pois para cada pergunta podem haver várias explicações.

Simplificando tudo, para sistemas simples, pode até esquecer o ENGINE, charset...

Vai direto criar as tabelas de acordo com as definições do servidor.
Prefiro UTF-8 no Banco de Dados e nas páginas e códigos.

O backup há como fazer no shell usando o mysql-dump, no painel de controle do site, ou você ter um script que faça isto para você. A maioria dos servidores tem o backup no pacote. Exceto se você tem um servidor dedicado sem a contratação de um técnico.

Para consistência, configurando os campos de acordos com os dados, criando os relacionamentos, e prefiro não inserir imagens no banco, somente o "path" de localização, assim o banco fica menor e a função dele seria para dados e não para armazenamento. :P